# Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache, visual-studio-code

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  //http://127.0.0.1:7545
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "19e947c0ff9005c1b68bf5eda8eb952c8945fc63ce3d67a771393a458ce0e8b1",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync(
    "/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi",
    "utf8"
  );
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**Following error is coming while deploying smart contract in visual studio code.**
**Am using Truffle-Ganache to get the private key**

```
Deploying, please wait...
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:609:54)
    at step (/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/home/surajsahoo/folder/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}
```

Comment: add hardhat config file to the question, and the command you are running

Comment: Command am running is : node deploy.js
\\
deploy.js is my file name

Comment: npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js

Comment: hardhat cannot detect the network. either the config file of hardhat is wrong or you are running the wrong command or the deployment script is not correct

Comment: @MajdTL can you check the code. I have attached the code. I am not using hardhat as of now